# Passing object values from php to jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I am using jQuery .ajax() to submit some values to db.php page where I retrieve additional records from my db. I use a class that returns the query results in a form of an object. I need to return that object back to original page in response and output it.

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url:  '/db.php',
   data: {
     'item': myItem
   },
   dataType : 'json',
   async: true,
   success: function (response) {

       // need returned values here

   }
});
```

**db.php**

```
$results = $db->get_results("
    SELECT *
    FROM t1
    WHERE id = " . $id );

// if I were to output my results here I'd do
// foreach ($results AS $res) {
//     $item = $res->item;
// }

echo '{ "res": '.$results.' }';
```

Now sure if I need to encode anything before passing it back to my JS...

Comment: PHP's `json_encode` is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

how about `json_encode()`

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

js:

```
success: function (response) {

   console.log(response)

   for(var i=0; i <response.length; i++){...}

}
```

edit: make sure you add `application/json; charset=utf-8` header, if not you'll need to parse the response `JSON.parse(response)`

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this with the result:

```
echo json_encode(array(
 'result' => $result,
));
```

and in your `success: function(response)`

```
success: function(response){
 response = JSON.parse(response);
 console.log(response);
}
```